# Let $X \subset \Bbb R$ be a set such that every continous function $f:X\to \Bbb R$ is bounded. Then X is compact.

Tags: real-analysis

Notice that $X$ is bounded, because the inclusion function $ic: X \to \Bbb R$, $ic(x) = x, \forall x \in X$, is continuous and $ic(X) = X$. Now, suppose $X$ is not closed. Then there exists $b \in X'$ but $b \notin X$. As we have $$\lim_{x\to b} \frac{1}{|x-b|} = +\infty$$   the continuous function $f(x)=\frac{1}{|x-b|}$, $\forall x \in X$ is not bounded, contradicting initial hypothesis. So, X must be closed, and therefore, compact.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Looks good to me!